# Auto slide viewpager behave strange and auto slides fastly

Tags: android-viewpager, autoscroll

I have used an Auto scroll banner viewpager of images in my app.First time the viewpager slides perfectly. But when i m returning back from some other fragment or activity or minimize the app, the viewpager auto scroll suddenly slides very fast and pages of viewpager overrides each other. Please help me out to resolve it.

Comment: I am refering this example

Comment: http://androhub.com/android-image-slider-using-viewpager/